# Instrumentation profiling for Windows store apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

We are developing a windows store app with XAML and we would like to run profiler of instrumentation type and get results with function execution timings (How long each function takes to execute).

But when we try to add the root project to the target on a instrumentation type profiling, it says "Switch to Sampling mode". If we switch to sampling mode, all that I can see is inclusive samples and exclusive samples. How to get function execution time tracks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this documentation from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974575.aspx) it lists it as not supported.

> These profiling features and options are not supported when profiling Windows Store apps
>
> - Profiling managed and native code using the instrumentation method.

I haven't been able to find any alternative solutions either.